# pyspark : Convert string to date format without minute, decod and hour

Tags: pyspark

Hello I would like to convert string date  to date format: 
for example from 190424  to 2019-01-24
I try with this code :

```
tx_wd_df = tx_wd_df.select(
    'dateTransmission', 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('dateTransmission', 'yymmdd')).alias('dateTransmissionDATE')
)
```

But I got this format : 2019-01-24 00:04:00 
I would like only 2019-01-24 
Any idea please?

Thanks

```
tx_wd_df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`to_date()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date). This will discard the rest of the date, and pick up only the format that matches the input date format string.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

date_column = "dateTransmission"
# MM because mm in Java Simple Date Format is minutes, and MM is months
date_format = "yyMMdd"
df = df.withColumn(date_column, F.to_date(F.col(date_column), date_format))
```